# Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing

Tags: java, spring, jetty, servlet-filters, spring-websocket

I read enough questions with answers on stackoverflow and no one helped me.
I tried to insert

```xml
<async-supported> true</async-supported>
```

everywhere but it doesn't help me, I also tried to annotate my custom filter with `@Async`
annotations without any results . I'm using `jetty 9.3.9.v20160517` ,
Java servlet dependency

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Plus I have a spring websocket configuration connected, everything works fine, but when I try to establish a connection to the server via the frontend using SockJS and Stomp, on the server I get this error in Google Chrome's console:

[image: Image from Google Chrome]

and this Java exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: Failed to open session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.handleInitialRequest (AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.handleRequestInternal (AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.JsonpPollingTransportHandler.handleRequestInternal (JsonpPollingTransportHandler.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.handleRequest (AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.java:65)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportHandlingSockJsService.handleTransportRequest (TransportHandlingSockJsService.java:314)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService.handleRequest (AbstractSockJsService.java:433)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest (SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle (HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch (DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService (DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest (FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet (FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service (FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:845)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1689)
at tnt.dom2.filter.HttpStatusFilter.doFilter (HttpStatusFilter.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1676)
at tnt.dom2.user.filter.UserActivityFilter.doFilter (UserActivityFilter.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1676)
at finch.portal.v3.web.controller.RequestHolderImpl.doFilter (RequestHolderImpl.java:48)
at finch.portal.v3.web.controller.RequestHolderFilter.doFilter (RequestHolderFilter.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1676)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at tnt.dom2.admin.AdminConfirmFilter.doFilter_aroundBody0 (AdminConfirmFilter.java:70)
at tnt.dom2.admin.AdminConfirmFilter$AjcClosure1.run (AdminConfirmFilter.java:1)
at org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_scheduling_aspectj_AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect$1$6c004c3eproceed (AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.aj:63)
at org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_scheduling_aspectj_AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect$1$6c004c3e (AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.aj:68)
at tnt.dom2.admin.AdminConfirmFilter.doFilter (AdminConfirmFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke (FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter (FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter (ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter (SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter (AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter (RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter (SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter (RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter (AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter (LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal (HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter (SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal (WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal (FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate (DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter (DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1676)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal (OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1676)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal (CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter (WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:581)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle (ContextHandler.java:1174)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope (ServletHandler.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope (SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1106)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle (ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle (HandlerCollection.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle (Server.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle (HttpChannel.java:319)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable (HttpConnection.java:253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded (AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable (FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run (SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume (ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume (ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run (ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue (Assert.java:92)
at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl.<init> (ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl.java:58)
at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest.getAsyncRequestControl (ServletServerHttpRequest.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.handleInitialRequest (AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.handleRequestInternal (AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.JsonpPollingTransportHandler.handleRequestInternal (JsonpPollingTransportHandler.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.handleRequest (AbstractHttpSendingTransportHandler.java:65)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.TransportHandlingSockJsService.handleTransportRequest (TransportHandlingSockJsService.java:314)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:845)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1689)
at tnt.dom2.filter.HttpStatusFilter.doFilter (HttpStatusFilter.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1676)
at tnt.dom2.user.filter.UserActivityFilter.doFilter (UserActivityFilter.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1676)
at finch.portal.v3.web.controller.RequestHolderImpl.doFilter (RequestHolderImpl.java:48)
at finch.portal.v3.web.controller.RequestHolderFilter.doFilter (RequestHolderFilter.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1676)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at tnt.dom2.admin.AdminConfirmFilter.doFilter_aroundBody0 (AdminConfirmFilter.java:70)
at tnt.dom2.admin.AdminConfirmFilter$AjcClosure1.run (AdminConfirmFilter.java:1)
at org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_scheduling_aspectj_AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect$1$6c004c3eproceed (AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.aj:63)
at org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_scheduling_aspectj_AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect$1$6c004c3e (AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.aj:68)
at tnt.dom2.admin.AdminConfirmFilter.doFilter (AdminConfirmFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke (FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter (FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter (ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter (SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter (AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter (RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter (SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter (RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter (AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter (LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal (HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter (SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal (WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal (FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate (DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter (DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1676)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal (OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1676)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal (CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter (OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter (WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:581)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle (ContextHandler.java:1174)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope (ServletHandler.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope (SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1106)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle (ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle (HandlerCollection.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle (Server.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle (HttpChannel.java:319)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable (HttpConnection.java:253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded (AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable (FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run (SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume (ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume (ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run (ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

this is my web.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <max-age>1209600</max-age>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-contexts/*Context.xml,</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <display-name>springSecurityFilterChain</display-name>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hvsf</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>requestHolderFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>finch.portal.v3.web.controller.RequestHolderFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>userActivityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>tnt.dom2.user.filter.UserActivityFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpStatusFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>tnt.dom2.filter.HttpStatusFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-contexts/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hvsf</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>requestHolderFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>userActivityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpStatusFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/media/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/f/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dev/f/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/freeze/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

websocket configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig  implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration webSocketTransportRegistration) {
        webSocketTransportRegistration.setSendTimeLimit(15 * 1000).setSendBufferSizeLimit(512 * 1024);
    }


    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration channelRegistration) {
        channelRegistration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(4).maxPoolSize(10);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> list) {
        DefaultContentTypeResolver resolver = new DefaultContentTypeResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        converter.setContentTypeResolver(resolver);
        list.add(converter);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `CharacterEncodingFilter` doesn't have `async-enabled`.

Comment: i can not add for CharacterEncodingFilter async-enabled

Comment: Why not? It is just an xml element in your `web.xml` why wouldn't you be able to add it.

Answer (score 4):

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

That filter is missing `<async-supported>true</async-supported>`.

Seeing as your mapping for that filter is ...

```xml
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

That means 100% of requests are going through it, which means it MUST have async-supported enabled if even one of your servlets has async-support enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The position of `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` tag is wrong.
you can put it just underneath `CharacterEncodingFilter` class name.

see below,

```xml
<filter>
   <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
   <async-supported>true</async-supported>  <!-- put in here -->
   <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
```